# Where to get CSS styles capable of styling buttons for IE 5,6, firefox 3?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Where to get CSS styles capable of styling buttons for IE 5,6, firefox 3? I need coloring (like light blue over default button color scheme)?

Comment: I understand that IE6 is still prevalent due to internal corporate custom sites.  But where in the world are you still finding IE5?  I only ask to make sure that, if it's a specific company, I never send a resume to them.

Comment: I found IE5 emulator  in my IE9 developer beta. Apparently all parts of my current site work in it correctly when set to IE5 mode=) (dynamic rounded corners, simple JS, etc) so I wondered how to style buttons for that ... peace of software=)

Comment: tloach was just referring to the fact that nobody uses IE5 anymore. Nobody even considers it when talking about browser support these days. We do still talk about IE6, but that's only because a fair number of corporate environments made the bad decisions which meant their internal applications wouldn't work with anything other than IE6, so they don't upgrade to IE7/IE8 or change to another browser because it would cost millions to make their applications work in them. The point is you *really* don't need to worry about IE5, and a lot of sites don't bother with IE6 anymore either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an old article from the days IE5 was still active;

http://www.webreference.com/programming/css_stylish/

Personal suggestion; stay away from IE specific effects like gradient.